# Scroll page down when the radio button click action perform hide div is shown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

```js
$("#docscrl").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('docscrlshw').position().top
  }, 'slow');
});
//doc show hide with scroll End 11.12.2020
//doc show hide with scroll start 11.12.2020
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.doc').on('click', function() {

    $('.docshw').show();
    //                $('.fcdyeshide').hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Table code start from here -->
<div class="col-md-12 col-12 table-responsive">
  <div class="form-group">

    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 10px !important;" align="center">
      <div class="form-group">code</div>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead class="lbbg3">
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 800px;">adfa</td>
          <td>Select Option &#40; &#10003; &#41;</td>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <!-- tr1 -->
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2" style="background: #eef7fc; text-align: left;">00</th>

          <table class="table table-hover">

            <thead class="">

              <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left; background: #f5f5f5;">
                Investments
              </td>
            </thead>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                Portfolio
              </td>
              <td style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table" id="docscrl">
                  <a href="#doc"> <input type="radio" id="customRadio50" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy doc">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio50" style="cursor: pointer;" onchange="valueChanged()"></label></a>


                </div>
              </td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                In Debt
              </td>
              <td style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table ">
                  <input type="radio" id="customRadio51" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio51" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>

                </div>
              </td>

            </tr>
          </table>



          <table class="table table-hover">

            <thead class="">

              <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left; background: #f7f7f9;">
                Direct
              </td>
            </thead>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                shares
              </td>
              <td style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                  <input type="radio" id="customRadio52" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio52" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>


                </div>
              </td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                shares
              </td>
              <td style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table ">
                  <input type="radio" id="customRadio53" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio53" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>

                </div>
              </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                property
              </td>
              <td style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table ">
                  <input type="radio" id="customRadio54" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio54" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>

                </div>
              </td>

            </tr>
          </table>



          <!-- 
                                                              Foreign Direct Investments  table end -->

          <!--   External commercial Borrowings table start -->
          <table class="table table-hover">

            <thead class="">

              <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left; background: #f7f7f9;">
                External
              </td>
            </thead>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                Close
              </td>
              <td style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                  <input type="radio" id="customRadio55" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio55" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>


                </div>
              </td>


            </tr>


          </table>

          <table class="table table-hover">

            <thead class="">

              <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left; background: #f7f7f9;">
                Others
              </td>
            </thead>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                sale
              </td>
              <td style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                  <input type="radio" id="customRadio56" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio56" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>


                </div>
              </td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                Indian
              </td>
              <td style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                  <input type="radio" id="customRadio57" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio57" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>


                </div>
              </td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                with a
              </td>
              <td style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                  <input type="radio" id="customRadio58" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio58" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>


                </div>
              </td>


            </tr>


          </table>

          <table class="table table-hover">
            <tbody>

              <thead class="">
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left; background: #eef7fc;">
                    03
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left; background: #f7f7f9;">Travel</td>
                </tr>


              </thead>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                  Travel
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadio59" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio59" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>


                  </div>
                </td>


              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                  for
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadio60" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio60" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>


                  </div>
                </td>


              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                  medical
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadio61" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio61" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>


                  </div>
                </td>


              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                  education
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadio62" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio62" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>


                  </div>
                </td>


              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                  including holiday
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadio63" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio63" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>


                  </div>
                </td>


              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>

          <table class="table table-hover">
            <tbody>

              <thead class="">
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left; background: #eef7fc;">
                    06
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left; background: #f7f7f9;">and P</td>
                </tr>


              </thead>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                  Other general
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadio64" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio64" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>


                  </div>
                </td>


              </tr>





            </tbody>
          </table>

          <table class="table table-hover">
            <tbody>

              <thead class="">
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left; background: #eef7fc;">
                    11
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left; background: #f7f7f9;">Personal</td>
                </tr>


              </thead>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                  courses
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadio65" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio65" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>


                  </div>
                </td>


              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                  r on-site)
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadio66" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio66" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>


                  </div>
                </td>


              </tr>




            </tbody>
          </table>

          <table class="table table-hover">
            <tbody>

              <thead class="">
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left; background: #eef7fc;">
                    13
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left; background: #f7f7f9;">Income</td>
                </tr>


              </thead>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                  family
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadio67" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input maint">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio67" style="cursor: pointer;" onchange="valueChanged()"></label>


                  </div>
                </td>


              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                  personal
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadio68" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio68" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>


                  </div>
                </td>


              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                  towards
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadio69" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio69" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>


                  </div>
                </td>


              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left;width: 800px;">
                  Outflows
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadio70" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio70" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>


                  </div>
                </td>


              </tr>




            </tbody>
          </table>

        </tr>
        <!-- tr1 end -->

        <tr>
          <td>

            <div class="col-md-12 col-12 radio-bg2 docshw docscrlshw" style="display: none;  overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden;">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h4 style="font-size: 22px;">Documentation</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-bottom: 15px;margin-top: -5px;"><span class="smallfont" style="line-height: 10px;">(The documents required)</span></div>
                <div class="col-md-12">

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <table class="table table-doc" width="100%">
                          <thead class="table-head">
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan="2" align="left" style="text-align: left; background: #eef7fc;">Education</td>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left">Eligibility</td>
                              <td align="left"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left">Limit</td>
                              <td align="left"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left"></td>
                              <td align="left">
                                <ul>
                                  <li></li>
                                  <li></li>
                                  <li></li>

                                </ul>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left">Remarks</td>
                              <td align="left">
                                <ul>
                                  <li></li>
                                  <li></li>
                                  <li></li>

                                </ul>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>



                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

          </td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hi, i am trying to scroll down the page at the show / hide div, on the above table i click on the first radio button is got selected then hide div is got displayed after the table completion. But some how my page is still on the top and scrolling is not getting happen.  i want to scroll down the page once the div tag is getting appear after the table. I hope you understand what is my requirement. Please help.

Comment: please can any one update on this

Comment: hey is there any luck on this